# Apple MapKit UI - TableView // No storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, mapkit

Attempted to make a mock up of the apple maps UI but whenever I do I table view on top of my search input view the UI doesn't format correctly. when I comment the table view the UI works according and doesn't look a mess. I'm 100% sure its the table view but not sure why this would be the case. Does anyone have any apple maps mock ups code? - I also program without storyboards on UIKit

```
func configureViewComponents() {
     backgroundColor = .white

     addSubview(indicatorView)
     indicatorView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 40, height: 8)
     indicatorView.centerX(inView: self)

     configureSearchBar()
     configureTableView()
     configureGestureRecognizers()
}

func configureSearchBar() {
     searchBar = UISearchBar()
     searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a place or address"
     searchBar.delegate = self
     searchBar.barStyle = .black
     searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)

     addSubview(searchBar)
     searchBar.anchor(top: indicatorView.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 8, width: 0, height: 50)
}

func configureTableView() {
     tableView = UITableView()
     tableView.rowHeight = 72
     tableView.delegate = self
     tableView.dataSource = self

     tableView.register(SearchCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

     addSubview(tableView)
     tableView.anchor(top: searchBar.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 100, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
}
```

[Tableview Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWVZk.png)

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwNKL.png)
[UI without the Table view code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUYIL.jpg)

Comment: Apple MapKit UI - func configureTableView() // NO STORYBOARDS

Comment: Provide examples of before/after of UI?

Comment: @HarryJ UI before and after been added

Comment: What library are you using for constraints?

Comment: extension file - i've imported UIKit and JGProgressHUD